# My HTML header and footer does not stretch when a scroll bar appears

Tags: html, css

I am  developing a website and I have reports in the content I wanted to have a scroll bar when the content overflows irrespective of the resolution.

I have used width 100% for both header and footer and I have a background repeat 1px strip. but when the content overflows and when the user Scrolls to see the data at the header and footer part I see white space as they don't strech.

I want them to strech till the End of Scroll

how do i get rid of this problem??

Comment: it would be more helpful if you post some code

Comment: please some code for better understanding

Comment: instead of code i actually wanted to post the Image itself but don't have the option as my reputation is not 10 yet

Comment: there are enough image hosts on the net

Comment: yes kuh-chan.. I have uploaded one.. pls look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by setting the `body` to `position:relative` and `float:left;`.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sftTB/1/).

```
body
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the width from your footer and header. Does my demo work for you?

Comment: yes jamie I tried removing width from Header and Footer.. Still it did not work

Comment: Then we need to see some code. Specfically the CSS for the body element and your header/footer as well as the CSS for the item contained the overflowing table.

Comment: the layout is like this------ there is a header, Container and a footer.and teh container has again a two divs left and right, left one has menu and right one shows the content, The content is Dynamic. The website was made fit for 1024 resolution and only in a few cases the content in the table overflows the viewport in such a case as a solution i have set the scroll for the window. when we scroll it the header and footer wil be still 100% for the initial window position. I want it to strech. can u please help

Comment: hey its solved... for the body tag if we write  DISPLAY:TABLE it works